# Nested lightning aura iteration

Tags: salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I have a nested aura:iteration like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.results}" var="res">                  
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ColumnsNameArr}" var="colName">
            <td>
                <div class="slds-truncate" >
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">{!res[colName]}}</a> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </aura:iteration>                    
    </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

How can I write correct {!res[colName]}? It is possible to do something like this in lightning?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to iterate the `res` property, what looks like to me of type `Map`. In Lightning Aura it's not possible to iterate over a `Map` (Apex) / `Object` (Javascript).

What you can do as solution would be to transform the `res` Map to a type of `Array` (Javascript) or in Apex to type of a `List`.

In Lightning Aura it is possible to iterate `Array`'s.

So how would that look like:

```js
{
  process: function() {
    var res = { a: 1, b: 2};
    var resArray = [];

    for (var key in res) {
      resArray.push({ 
        key: key, 
        value: res[key] 
      });
    }

    // now, from here on you can use the 'resArray' to iterate in your Aura component

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Use the iteration variable at the next level down.
I think this will work...

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.results}" var="res">                  
<tr class="slds-hint-parent">
    <aura:iteration items="{!res.ColumnsNameArr}" var="colName">
        <td>
            <div class="slds-truncate" >
                <a href="javascript:void(0);">{!colName}}</a> 
            </div>
        </td>
    </aura:iteration>                    
</tr>
```